# Video.JS - Using API to do functions

Tags: video.js

Does Video.JS provide a JS API that I can use to trigger specific events?
For example, I want to hide the player's controls and have a separate button to go fullscreen or mute/unmute the player.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Check this doc for the available methods: http://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html

Get the player:

```
var player = videojs('id_of_player');
```

Hide controls:

```
player.controls(false);
```

Fullscreen:

```
player.requestFullscreen();
```

Mute:

```
player.muted(true);
```